# Link pyqtproperty to QlineEdit value

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm looking for a way to bind a pyqtProperty available in my python model to a QLineEdit value in my view and in the other side. I can connect them in both direction but I think it would be easier to link them directly.
Is this solution possible ?